# How to use a dropdown list to pass paramater from a JSP to a Controller?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

so I am using bootstrap in my JSP and I have the the dropdown list below and I am trying to pass `dropDownList` as a paramater to a servlet/controller mapped to `Home` where I can query a database based on the value of `dropDownList`. I have everything set up on the servlet/controller to receive and query the database, but I can't get the dropdown list to pass the parameter. Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

```
   <form action="Home" method="post">
            <select class="form-control" name="dropDownList">
                <option selected value="default"> Please select an option</option>
                <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
                <option value="Restrooms">Restroom</option>
                <option value="Vending machine">Vending Machine</option>
                <option value="Food & Drink">Food & Drink</option>
                <option value="Parking Kiosk">Parking Kiosk</option>
                <option value="Ramp">Ramp</option>
            </select>
    </form>
```

The part of the sever side where I am getting the parameter is as followed:

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String type= request.getParameter("dropDownList");
    }
```

Comment: can you show your server side code too where you are trying to get dropdown selected value ? it should be something like      `String selected_value = request.getParameter("dropDownList") ;`

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi I added the code you requested, it's essentially what you had in min

Answer (score 0):

Use this at server side

```
String  selectedItem;
    if(request.getParameter("dropDownList")!=null)
    {
       selectedItem=request.getParameter("dropDownList");
    }
```

Comment: `@Sreejesh K Nair`. The problem is that it always comes up as null, the parameter never get's passed. I fount a work around using `<input type ="submit" class= "btn btn-default" > ` in the form, but I am trying to avoid having the user click one more button in order to select an option.

Comment: @Squanchinator.  You should use doGet() when you want to intercept on HTTP GET requests. You should use doPost() when you want to intercept on HTTP POST requests.

Comment: `@Sreejesh K Nair` that is precisely what I did as you can tell from my post I used `method = "post" ` in the form and intercepted in `doPost()` in my controller. Any more bright ideas?